# Dynamic import is not working in react app

Tags: reactjs, dynamic-import

I have CRA and then i use npm eject.

I want to import file dynamically but it is giving error

> Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

**Error is in this file**

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { pathParam1, pathParam2 } = { ...this.props.match.params };
    /* eslint-disable */
    import('raw-loader!../../'+pathParam1+'/'+pathParam2) // eslint-disable-line
    .then( (data)=>{
      console.log('done')
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
```

and webpackfile is untouched. 
Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use import inside a react lifecycle, instead use it at the top of your files before declaring your class.

Comment: So how will i import files who's name I choose from props ?

Comment: Try this workaround it may help https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/562

Comment: Side note: use this syntax for better readability ``` import(`raw-loader!../../${pathParam1}/${pathParam2}`) ```